# Windows 8 C#: Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.ImageSource change Image

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, microsoft-metro, converters

**WARNING** There are two different `ImageSource`s in Windows API

- System.Windows.Media.ImageSource = The one of Windows Forms
- Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.ImageSource = The one of Windows Store Apps

I'm a beginner in C# and Windows 8 Metro Style App programming stuff.

But if you want to edit the image of a `Image`, the "old" method with BitmapImage won't work:

XAML:

```
<Image Source="http://image.source.de" x:Name="Image1" />
```

Code-Behind C#:

```
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage...
```

won't work. The compiler will say something like

> "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" can't be converted to "Windows.Ui.Xaml.Media.ImageSource"
>
> > (Yes, `BitmapImage` can usually be converted to `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource`)

(System.Windows.Media.Imaging isn't anymore in the default import list of Visual Studio for Windows (StoreApps), you need to bind PresentationCore.dll first.)

So - is there any solution to edit Image1.Source than using `Binding`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
Image.Source = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new System.Uri("http://image.source.de"))
```

Comment: `ConvertFromString` is located in TypeConverter.dll, which is located only in old-version System.dll, the newer one (I use 4.5.1) hasn't got that TypeConverter :(

Comment: I have updated the answer. I should remember ImageSourceConverter works on WPF and WP7, but not in WinRT. BitmapImage should definitely work on RT, assuming "http://image.source.de" is a valid url.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. For local files, I used `(new System.Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/pic.png")`